# Edit file with Excel without reformatting

Tags: csv

I use a program which only imports `csv` files, but the first 5 columns ***must*** be empty, without any data in it.

When I'm editing the file to add or change some data, and save `csv` file, the mandatory first 5 free columns are deleted automatically.

How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 2):

You could use Notepad++ and a RegEx to manually insert the commas you need into the output files.

Here is my test file. I saved it in Excel and selected CSV format.

[image: CSV file with 5 blank columns, then 2 filled columns]

Upon opening it, we can see it generates the CSV error you're talking about. Thanks a lot, Microsoft!

[image: CSV file with 2 filled columns]

Open Notepad++. Turn on RegEx replace and Wrap Around. Then type the following code for find and replace.

```
Find: ^(\w)
Replace: ,,,,,\1
```

[image: RegEx to add 5 commas to the beginning of each line in Notepad++ Pt 1]

Hit Replace All to make the changes. Then save the document.

[image: RegEx to add 5 commas to the beginning of each line in Notepad++ Pt 2]

Re-open the file in Microsoft Excel and you're back to having your 5 blank columns at the beginning. :)

[image: CSV file with 5 blank columns, then 2 filled columns]

Comment: +1, a slightly more elegant version of my suggestion (that also uses Notepad++ :), I never noticed that its Find+Replace supported RegEx!

Answer (score 1):

You can enter the formula `=""` (meaning an empty string) in cell A1.  In this way Excel will preserve the blank columns when you save it as `csv` again.

Please note that, however, since the formula will not be actually written into the `csv` file, you will need to use this trick each time after you re-open the file.

Comment: i tried it but it seems when i convert excel file back to csv the format is changing and the program didn't import that back...

Comment: Mind posting extract of the contents of your csv file before and after saving?  You can open the csv file with notepad to read its contents.

Comment: yes, i can open with notepad and read, also if i change some data in notepad and than save as csv i can import to my program back. but the problem is if i open it via excel and change the same data (what i changed in notepad) and after converting back into csv it didn't import...

Comment: What I meant was, can you post two or three lines of your csv here?  Because I found it good with my own test data.  Also, what is the Excel version you are using?

Answer (score 1):

Open up your *.csv file in Notepad, hold the `Alt` key and at the start of the first line, drag your mouse all the way down to the last row to enable `Box Selection`.  Then type in 5 commas, which will populate them on all lines.

Alternatively, you can hold down `Alt` + `Shift` and then use the arrow keys

This also gets around having to open the file in Excel which can cause issues with the original data.

EDIT: After some quick research, it appears that this is not supported using the native `Notepad` application in Windows, but is supported in multiple other editor applications.  You can download something like `Notepad++` (Freeware) to accomplish this.

Comment: +1 for teaching me something new about Notepad++. Your solution is also faster than mine. :D

Answer (score 0):

Insert a header row, with dummy column names if you wish, which will force excel to preserve the empty columns.

Comment: @chipperyman573 It *does* provide an answer that, although possibly incorrect (I haven't tested), is an answer *per se* and addresses the original question.

Comment: Sorry, I misread it last night.

Answer (score 0):

Your question seems to imply that you are opening a CSV file with Excel using the default settings (as in, double-clicking). Depending on your source file, as in your case, this can lead to various data-corruptions. There are some issues concerning csv files (plain text data) that you should be aware of, to avoid data corruption when manipulating the data with Excel.

I've written an in depth overview of these issues here: http://theonemanitdepartment.wordpress.com/2014/12/15/the-absolute-minimum-everyone-working-with-data-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-file-types-encoding-delimiters-and-data-types-no-excuses/

You should learn how to import and export data to/from Excel, keeping the above issues in mind.